# Change of Basis, Linear Mapping, Coordinate Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

Okay this may be a bit long. Only the last question is an issue for me but I can't verify whether the earlier questions (which affect the last) are done correctly.

**Given
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(x,y,z) = (x+2y-z,x+z,4x-4y+5z)
\end{eqnarray*}
for $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.**

**1) Find the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.**

My answer: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x,2y,-z) &=& x(1,0,0)+ 2y(0,1,0) -z(0,0,1)\\
(x,0,z) &=& x(1,0,0)+ 0(0,1,0) +z(0,0,1)\\
(4x,-4y,5z) &=& 4x(1,0,0)-4y(0,1,0) +5z(0,0,1)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

$T = \left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2&-1\\
1&0&1\\
4&-4&5
\end{matrix}
\right).$

**2) Find the matrix $A$ of $T$ with respect to the ordered basis $e = \{(-1,1,2),(-2,1,4),(-1,1,4)\}$.**

My answer: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x,2y,-z) &=& a_1(-x,y,2z)+ b_1(-2x,y,4z) +c_1 (-x,y,4z)\\
(x,0,z) &=& a_2(-x,y,2z)+ b_2(-2x,y,4z) + c_2(-x,y,4z)\\
(4x,-4y,5z) &=& a_3(-x,y,2z)+ b_3(-2x,y,4z) +c_3(-x,y,4z).
\end{eqnarray*}
$A =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a_1&b_1&c_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3
\end{matrix}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
4.5&-3&0.5\\
-0.5&-1&1.5\\
-10.5&0&6.5
\end{matrix}
\right).$

**3) Find the coordinate vector $[v]_e$ when $v = (1,0,2)$.**

My answer: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1,0,2) &=& a(-1,1,2) + b(-2,1,4)+ c(-1,1,4)
\end{eqnarray*}
$[v]_e = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
a\\b\\c
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
-1\\-1\\2
\end{matrix}
\right].$

**4) Find $T(v)$ and $[T(v)]_e$.**

\begin{eqnarray*}
T(v) &=& 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2&-1\\
1&0&1\\
4&-4&5
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1\\0\\2
\end{matrix}
\right)\\
&=& 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-1\\3\\4
\end{matrix}
\right).\\
\text{[}T(v)\text{]}_e 
&=&
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2&-1\\
1&0&1\\
4&-4&5
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-1\\-1\\2
\end{matrix}
\right)\\
&=&
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-5\\1\\10
\end{matrix}
\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

**5. Verify that $[T(v)]_e = A[v]_e:$**

\begin{eqnarray*}
A[v]_e &=& 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
4.5&-3&0.5\\
-0.5&-1&1.5\\
-10.5&0&6.5
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-1\\-1\\2
\end{matrix}
\right)\\
&=&
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-0.5\\4.5\\23.5
\end{matrix}
\right)\\
&\neq& [T(v)]_e
\end{eqnarray*}

I think I misunderstood the difference between $T[v]_e$ and $[T(v)]_e$ (I assumed they're the same) but I don't know what is the difference.

Comment: $T[v]_e$ is nonsensical. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3577264/265466 for a lengthy explanation of why. It would help you keep things straight not to use the same name for the linear transformation $T$ and its matrix w/r the standard basis.

Comment: You should check your work. For instance, $T(-1,1,2)=(-1,1,2)$, so the first column of $A$ should be $(1,0,0)^T$, which is not what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition 5.1.3.** Let $T : \mathbb{K}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^m$ be a linear transformation and define the matrix
$A \in \mathbb{M}^{m \times n}(\mathbb{K})$ to be the matrix whose $j$-th column is $T(ij)$, i.e.

\begin{eqnarray*}
A = [T(i_1) \dots T(i_n)]
\end{eqnarray*}
where {i_1 \dots i_n} is the standard basis of $\mathbb{K}^n$. Then for every $x \in \mathbb{K}^n, x = x_1i_1 + \dots x_n i_n$,
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(x) = T(x_1i_1 + \dots x_ni_n) = x_1T(i_1) + \dots  x_nT(i_n) = Ax.
\end{eqnarray*}

That is, the action of $T$ can be expressed in terms of the matrix $A$ and we call $A$ the matrix of the linear transformation $T$.

**Lemma 5.2.1.** If $e = \{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $P = [e_1 \dots e_n]$ is the matrix with $e_1, \dots, e_n$ as its columns, then $[v]_e = P^{-1}v$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Proof. $P[v]_e = [e_1 \dots e_n]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n
\end{matrix}
\right]
= x_1e_1 + \cdots + x_ne_n = v.
$
Hence
$[v]_e = P^{-1}v.$

Source of Definition and Lemma: [Lecture Notes - Linear Algebra Spring 2020](https://gtvault-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/ashahrir3_gatech_edu/EWq0DlvOEkFPvqJ_-UIvucQB0ghTGDTBc5mFAEcCfuykDg?e=VNs3QU)

**Solution**

Given
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(x,y,z) = (x+2y-z,x+z,4x-4y+5z)
\end{eqnarray*}
for $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

1. With respect to the standard basis $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$, the matrix $A$ of $T$ can be found by using Definition 5.1.3 which states that in this case:
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   A = [T(i_1) \quad T(i_2) \quad T(i_3)],
   \end{eqnarray*}

where $i_1, i_2, i_3$ are the standard basis $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ respectively.

\begin{eqnarray*}
T(i_1) &=& T(1,0,0)\\
&=& (1 + 0 - 0, 1 + 0, 4 -0 + 0)^T\\
&=& (1,1,4)^T.\\
T(i_2) &=& T(0,1,0)\\
&=& (2,0,-4)^T.\\
T(i_2) &=& T(0,0,1)\\
&=& (-1,1,5)^T.
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus, $A = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2&-1\\
1&0&1\\
4&-4&5
\end{matrix}
\right).
$

2. With respect to the ordered basis $e = \{(-1,1,2),(-2,1,4),(-1,1,4)\}$, the matrix $A$ of $T$ can also be found by using Definition 5.1.3.

Let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ represent the three vectors of $e = \{(-1,1,2),(-2,1,4),(-1,1,4)\}$ respectively.

\begin{eqnarray*}
T(e_1) &=& T(-1,1,2)\\
&=& (-1,1,2)^T.\\
T(e_2) &=& T(-2,1,4)\\
&=& (-4,2,8)^T.\\
T(e_3) &=& T(-1,1,4)\\
&=& (-3,3,12)^T.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Next, we'll express $T(e_1), T(e_2), T(e_3)$ as linear combinations of $e_1, e_2, e_3.$

\begin{eqnarray*}
T(e_1) &=& 1(-1,1,2)^T + 0(-2,1,4)^T + 0(-1,1,4)^T\\
&=& 1e_1+ 0e_2+ 0e_3\\
\text{[}T(e_1)\text{]}_e &=& (1,0,0)^T.\\
T(e_2) &=& 0e_1+ 2e_2+ 0e_3.\\\text{[}T(e_2)\text{]}_e &=& (0,2,0)^T.\\
T(e_3) &=& 0e_1+ 0e_2+ 3e_3.\\\text{[}T(e_3)\text{]}_e &=& (0,0,3)^T.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus, 
$
A =  
[\text{[}T(e_1)\text{]}_e \quad \text{[}T(e_2)\text{]}_e \quad \text{[}T(e_3)\text{]}_e]
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&3
\end{matrix}
\right).
$

3. Now we'll find the coordinate vector $\text{[}v\text{]}_e$ when $v = (1,0,2)$ using Lemma 5.2.1.

Let $P$ represent the matrix with the ordered basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ as its columns:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P &=& 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-1&-2&-1\\
1&1&1\\
2&4&4
\end{matrix}
\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
[v]_e
&=& P^{-1}v\\
&=& \left(
\begin{matrix}
-1&-2&-1\\
1&1&1\\
2&4&4
\end{matrix}
\right)^{-1}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1\\0\\2
\end{matrix}
\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

We can find the inverse of $P$ through the following:

i) Matrix of Minors, $M$, of $P = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0&2&2\\
-4&-2&0\\
-1&0&1
\end{matrix}
\right).
$

ii) Matrix of Cofactors, $C$, of $M = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0&-2&2\\
4&-2&0\\
-1&0&1
\end{matrix}
\right).
$

iii) Adjugate of $C = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0&4&-1\\
-2&-2&0\\
2&0&1
\end{matrix}
\right).
$

iv) Determinant of $P = 
-1(0) + 2(2) -1(2) = 2.$

v) Inverse of $P, P^{-1}= 
\frac{1}{2}C = \frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0&4&-1\\
-2&-2&0\\
2&0&1
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0&2&-0.5\\
-1&-1&0\\
1&0&0.5
\end{matrix}
\right).
$

Thus, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
[v]_e
&=& P^{-1}v\\
&=& \left(
\begin{matrix}
0&2&-0.5\\
-1&-1&0\\
1&0&0.5
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1\\0\\2
\end{matrix}
\right)\\
&=& 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-1\\-1\\2
\end{matrix}
\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

4. Let us find $T(v)$ and $[T(v)]_e$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
T(v) &=& T(1,0,2)\\
&=& (-1, 3, 14)^T.
\end{eqnarray*}

Expressing $T(v)$ as a linear combination of $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$, we get:
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(v) &=& (-1,3,14)^T\\
&=& a(e_1) + b(e_2) + c(e_3)\\
&=& a(-1,1,2) + b(-2,1,4) + c(-1,1,4)\\
&=& -1(-1,1,2) -2 (-2,1,4) + 6(-1,1,4).
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence, $[T(v)]_e = (-1,-2,6)^T$.

5. Verifying that $[T(v)]_e = A[v]_e:$

\begin{eqnarray*}
A[v]_e &=& 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&3
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-1\\-1\\2
\end{matrix}
\right)\\
&=& 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-1\\-2\\6
\end{matrix}
\right).\\
\\
\text{[}T(v)\text{]}_e
&=& 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-1\\-2\\6
\end{matrix}
\right) \quad \text{(from part (4.))}.\\
\\
A[v]_e &=& \text{[}T(v)\text{]}_e\\
\text{[}T(v)\text{]}_e &=& A[v]_e.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$$T(v)=Tv=[Tv]_e^T\left(\begin{array}{c}
-1 & 1& 2\\
-2 & 1& 4\\
-1 & 1& 4\\
\end{array}\right)$$
$$Tv=A[v]_e^T\left(\begin{array}{c}
-1 & 1& 2\\
-2 & 1& 4\\
-1 & 1& 4\\
\end{array}\right)$$
I suggest you read the chapter of linear thranformation about any linear algebra textbook.